# Can i generate dashboards through Power BI and publish it directly to clients website?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-embedded

I am newbie to web technology ,so i am not able to get the steps for doing this.
I will have data fetched from data base and do some report generation and dashboarding in power BI.
I need to integrate the dashboards and reports on weekly basis to clients website.
Do i need to generate apis or some other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Publish to web option. You can copy either a url to your report or the html code you can then embed wherever you want. You can find Publish to web in the report menu. If it is not there, ask your global admin to activate it in settings.